# Validating XML parsed with ElementTree, possible?

Tags: python, xml, xsd, dtd, elementtree

Am I correct in that ElementTree does not support DTD or XSD? Is there a means of plugging anything into ElementTree to support validation, preferrably via XML Schema?

Answer (score 2):

I would try using the lxml library; it supports etree representations and validation.